# Forever start with nodejs server

Tags: node.js, npm, forever

I have this `package.json` file. I can easily run `npm start` and `npm run dev` by which my server starts at `3000` port. But I need to run it forever using `forever npm`.

```
{
  "name": "micro-stripe-charge",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "micro",
    "dev": "micro-dev"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "micro-dev": "^3.0.0"
  }
}
```

I have tried this command but doesn't work

```
forever start node_modules/micro
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
forever start -c "npm start" ./
```

And you should get server up in `forever list`

To stop process use `forever stop 0` where zero is index - `[0]`

Also in `forever list` OR `lsof -I:<port>` like `lsof -i:3000` you get `PID`

You can stop process by `kill -QUIT <PID>`

Comment: Updated answer with stopping process

Comment: What is `0` here `forever stop 0`?

Comment: Thank you very much